# State resolve not working in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm using [this tutorial](http://blog.thejsj.com/angular-js-authentication-with-ui-router/) to figure out my authentication system for a web app that I am working on. I'm using ui-router's StateProvider and resolve system to reroute the user to the home page if they attempt to access one of the pages that needs authentication. Everything seems to be working, except that the resolve part doesn't seem to be actually working - i.e. my authenticate returns a rejected promise, yet the page loads like normal, despite the fact that there should be some sort of error because of this. What am I doing wrong?

app.states.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(routeConfig);

/** @ngInject */
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  // checks if user is logged in or not
  // passes back rejected promise if not, resolved promise if true
  function authenticated(authFactory, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    authFactory.authenticate()
      .then(function(authenticate) {
        if (authenticate.data === 'true') {
          deferred.resolve();
        } else {
          deferred.reject();
        }
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  // every new state that should include a sidebar must have it as a view
  $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
          url: '/dashboard/',
          views: {
            'sidebar': {
              templateUrl: 'app/components/navbar/sidebar.html',
              controller: 'SidebarController as vm'
            },
            'content': {
              templateUrl: 'app/components/authenticated/dashboard.html',
              controller: 'DashboardController as vm'
            }
          },
          resolve: {
            authenticated: authenticated
          }
        })
```

app.run.js

```
function runBlock($rootScope, $log, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function () {
      // Redirect user to forbidden page
      $state.go('forbidden');
    });
  }
```

auth.factory.js

'use strict';

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('authFactory', authFactory);

authFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$cookies'];

function authFactory($http, $cookies) {
  var _token;
  var service = {
    authenticate: authenticate
  };
  return service;

  // used to prevent user from accessing pages that they shouldn't have access to
  // this is used exclusively in app.routes.js/app.states.js
function authenticate() {
     // gets user's token from cookies, if no cookie, _token will be blank and server will return 403
    // this part might be redundant with other functions, but I left it in for now just to make sure
    if ($cookies.getObject('user')) {
      _token = $cookies.getObject('user').token;
    } else {
      _token = '';
    }
    var request = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/checkToken',
      headers: {'x-auth-token': _token},
      transformResponse: function(data) {
        return data;
      }
    });
    return request;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place `return deferred.promise` outside then function, so that promise will get returned properly.

**Code**

```
function authenticated(authFactory, $q, $log) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  authFactory.authenticate()
  .then(function(authenticate) {
    if (authenticate.data === 'true') {
      deferred.resolve();
    } else {
      deferred.reject();
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise; //placed outside function
}
```

Comment: Yikes, don't know how I missed that, your answer worked immediately. Should I delete this question? As it was such a specific error?

Comment: @turner I don't think so you should delete the question..Keep as is..Probably It will help someone.. :)

Comment: @turner - this may indeed help me because I am facing a similar scenario regarding user authentication. However, I don't understand where you inject your `authFactory` into `app.states`.

Comment: @bob sorry for the long response time, I have updated both of app.states and auth.factory with my full code, so hopefully that will be some help to you. I never had to explicitly inject authFactory, but whether that's because it's unnecessary or because I have the ngInject annotation in there, I'm not sure. I can test it when I get home in a few hours.

Comment: no worries. I ended up not using resolve anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619496/using-resolve-in-ui-router-to-authenticate-a-user/32619725?noredirect=1#comment53243111_32619725