# Using resolve in ui-router to authenticate a user

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a issue in my Angular app with regards to the `resolve` section of the `ui-router`. I'm trying to present a `login modal` the first time a user hits the website.

In my app.config.js, how do I inject my `'loginService'`:

```js
angular
    .module('rage')
    .config(config);

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard.html",
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            data: { pageTitle: 'RAGE', requireLogin: true },
            resolve: {

                 // *** WHERE DO I INJECT 'loginService' ? ***

                authUser: function () {
                    return loginService.loginModal().then(function (user) {
                        $rootScope.userID = user.userId;
                        userService.openUserSession(razorEnvJson).then(function (data) {
                            // assign some scope vars here..
                        });
                    })
                }
            }
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "app/views/login-view.html",
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
}
```

loginService code:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('rage').service('loginService',
        ['$rootScope', '$modal', 'datacontext', 'userService', login]);

    function login($rootScope, $modal, datacontext, userService) {
        var modalInstance = null
        
        this.loginModal = function(){
            modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl as login',      
            });            
            return modalInstance.result.then(function (user) {                
                return user;
            });
            
        };

    }
})();
```

LoginCtrl controller code:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('rage').controller('LoginCtrl',
        ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modalInstance', '$q', 'datacontext', 'userService', authenticate]);

    function authenticate($rootScope, $scope, $modalInstance, $q, datacontext, userService) {

        var login = this;

        // OK,CANCEL CLICK EVENTS FROM MODAL !!!
        $scope.ok = function () {
            //  var user = userService.authenticateWebUser();  // **** TBD ****              
            var user = {userId: login.userId, pswd: login.pswd};
            $modalInstance.close(user);
        };
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    }
})();
```

I've also attempted `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'` event inside `app.js` to transition the state from `main` to `login`, but that hangs up on me.

**** MY UPDATED APP.CONFIG.JS CODE, SEPT 18 ****

Here is the proper usage of `resolve:` using `ui-router` states.

```js
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard.html",
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    data: { pageTitle: 'RAGE', requireLogin: true },
    resolve: {
 authUser: ['$rootScope', 'loginService', 'userService', function ($rootScope, loginService, userService) {
     return loginService.loginModal().then(function (user) {
  $rootScope.userID = user.userId;
  initSession(user, $rootScope, loginService, userService); 
     })
 }]
    }
})
.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "app/views/login-view.html",
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
}
function initSession(user, $rootScope, loginService, userService) {

    userService.getInitParams().then(function (envJson) {
        // some code omitted here...
 userService.openUserSession(envJson).then(function (data) {
     var sessionID = data.data[0];
     $rootScope.rageSessionVars.sessionID = sessionID;
     $rootScope.rageSessionVars.userID = $rootScope.userID; // *** HOW TO SUSPEND ALL CODE UNTIL userID IS ASSIGNED ??? ***
     console.log("sessionID = " + sessionID);

     $rootScope.rageSessionVars.currDashboardName = "Default";
 });
           
    });

}
```

*** MainCtrl controller code ***

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage')
        .controller('MainCtrl',
            ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$interval', '$window', '$state', '$location', 'widgetDefinitions',
            'defaultWidgets', 'gadgetInitService', main]);

    function main($rootScope, $scope, $interval, $window, $state, $location, widgetDefinitions, defaultWidgets, gadgetInitService, authUser) {
        var main = this;
           
        **** authUser IS NEVER DEFINED !!!

        if ($scope.userID == undefined) {   /// *** NOTHING WORKS HERE !!! ***
            //$state.go('login');
            //$location.url('index.html#/?login');
            //return ;
        }

        if ($scope.userID == undefined) {
            main.userName = "risk user";
        }
        else {
            $scope.main.userName = $scope.userID;   
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

I see your getting confused on the use of 'Resolve'.
It should be used when you want some data passed into the controller when it's being run. Not to run a function before initiating a controller.

This isn't what you really want in this situation.

It kinda depends on your authentication method, cookies/tokens etc. 
Here is a similar method that I would follow.

- Have a Login service which handles the following
  -- Login/Logout of the user
  -- Checks if the user is authenticated
- In your Controller call your service to check if the user is logged in.
  -- If the user is not logged in, then prompt login screen
  -- If the user is logged in, then let the controller continue execution
- How I handle it, is whenever the user makes an UnAuthorised request where the server returns a 401 response I call my LoginService to prompt the login screen again.
- I use an authInterceptor in Angular to catch any 401 response from the server.
  Here is a nice guide on it: http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/

This allows you to write your Unauthorized handler in one place.

Hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: injecting `loginService` now works, based on your answer ! But I don't understand how to pass in `authUser` to MainCtrl. Is that passing by default, and I just have to add a parameter to MainCtrl ?

Comment: Just add 'authUser' as a parameter to your 'MainCtrl'. Be sure it's the same name as used in the 'resolve'. The parameter will be populated by ui-router for you in the 'resolve'. Then in the 'MainCtrl' you can check if 'authUser' has a value. If it does not then redirect to the login screen.

Comment: I've added `'MainCtrl'` module above, but `authUser` is not passed in at all. Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect what you're looking for. I don't believe a resolve it what you need.

Comment: the resolve was an excellent tutorial for me, and it did actually work. I was still able to assign the userID onto the $scope object, which was then available on the MainCtrl controller code. However, I'm seeing now that there are better solutions (i.e. using app.js to check for a user authentication without the resolve). Thank you again.